# Add a timing event in the background with JavaScript, in a HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a timing event in the background with JavaScript, in an HTML File.

What should happen is that, when I click *Log In* on my login page then it should come to these for 5 seconds and after it should go to the next page.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Loading Screen</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
<div class="box">
  <div class="b b1"></div>
  <div class="b b2"></div>
  <div class="b b3"></div>
  <div class="b b4"></div>

  <style>



</div>
</html>
```

If I need to add this the code in the styles file this is my `style.css`

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #e55039;
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box .b {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left: 4px solid;
    border-right: 4px solid;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: ro 2s infinite;
}

.box .b1 {
    border-color: #4a69bd;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.box .b2 {
    border-color: #f6b93b;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.box .b3 {
    border-color: #2ecc71;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.box .b4 {
    border-color: #34495e;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes ro {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-400deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(200deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the whole page to a different page after 5 seconds?

Comment: @Martin He says that at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to accomplish automatically redirecting the current page.

You initially said JavaScript, so here is a JS solution:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = 'my_new_page.htm';
}, 5000);
```

This will redirect the page to `my_new_page.htm` (change to your desired page) after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

You could also use a standard redirect, which doesn't require JavaScript at all:

```
<head>
    ... Other head HTML
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=my_new_page.htm" />
</head>
```

Just place the `meta` tag in your `head` and the page will automatically redirect after 5 seconds to `my_new_page.htm`.